# Initializing Member Instances in C ++

Tags: c++

I feel really stupid but I have some trouble finding the right search terms for this (probably easy) question. I think that with some code my issue is easy to understand.

I have a class that has, as a member, an instance of another class. So I go:

```
class Engine {
    sf::Window window_;
}
```

Then in my `.cpp` file:

```
Engine::Engine() {
    window_ = sf::Window(200,100);
}
```

I actually didn't know this was the wrong way to do things until I got *"Object of type sf::Window cannot be assigned because its copy operator is implicitly deleted"* for this particular class. I understand that I'm supposed to do `sf::Window window(200,100)`, but how do I combine that with creating a member variable in my class (`window_`)?

Comment: Your C++ book covers member initialisation. Which book is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the constructor initialization list to *initialize* data members:

```
Engine::Engine() : window_(200,100)
{
}
```

What you are attempting to do is to *assign* to a default constructed instance. This is because, once you are in the constructor's body, all data members (and base classes) have already been initialized.

Comment: and that is, if I am not mistaken, one of the main uses of initialization lists, correct?

Comment: @user2018675 Yes. If you want anything other than a default initialization, you need to use the initialization list.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand the difference between initialization and assignment before :). Quick add-on: So if a particular data member has no arguments, (e.g. `sf::Clock clock_()` ). **a)** can I simply leave it out of the initialization list and it will be constructed automatically? **b)** Is that good style?

Comment: @Noio It is a bit complicated. You get default initialization for all types. The issue is that sometimes default initialization does not do much. For example, when built-in types are default initialized, there is no initialization performed. So if you have built-ins and you want them to be zero-initialized, you *have* to use the initialization list. A similar thing happens to aggregate types which hold built-ins. But if your data members have default constructors, these will be called, whether you initialize explicitly in the initialization list or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can either do it via member initialization list

```
Window() : window_(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "title") {}
```

or by calling `window_.create(arguments)`

Comment: If I do `window_.create(arguments)` I will have essentially constructed the `sf::Window` twice, no? Is that bad?

Comment: you should't do both of those in one constructor, if you do it in initialization list, you will construct it at place, if you call it from within the constructor's body, it will first call default constructor of window, which does nothing and then call `create`, which will basically initialize the window(you may think about it as the constructor does the same thing if arguments are passed)